# Convert a letter to its ascii decimal form

Tags: c++, type-conversion

i am in a basic programming class and know practically nothing about programming, we are using c++ and my current project is to pull up the console and do the following

1. input a letter and output its ascii decimal equivalent
2. input a number between 33 and 254 and output its letter equivalent
3. input a lower case letter and output itscapital
4. input a number of hours and output the number of minutes
5. input a number greater than 60 and output the number of hours and minutes

this is the work i have so far

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main ()  
{  
    cout<<"Assignment 2"<<endl;
    char somechar;
    int charval;
    int input_number;
    char output_letter2;
    char input_lower_letter;
    char output_upper_letter;
    int input_hours;
    int output_minutes;
    int input_minutes2;
    int output_hours2;
    int output_remainder_minutes;

    cout<<"Enter a letter"<<endl;
    cin>>somechar>>endl;
    cout<< somechar='a';
    int charval = somechar;
    printf("%c = %d\n",somechar,charval);

    system("pause");
}
```

any tips and help are deeply appreciated

Comment: Don't you have class mates or a teacher for these kind of things?

Comment: the teacher wont give me the answers to the homework, and i guess i should befriend someone in the class

Comment: The idea for learning is to ask the right questions to understand how to solve the problem. You have probably already learnt the material to solve this in class. Most people here want to solve questions that are not for purely educational purposes.

Comment: So you've submitted your code for review, but haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: what i really need is the function to convert a letter into its ascii decimal, which i did state in the title if youll direct your attention there

Comment: @turb But in your code, you already do it.  The only thing that might go wrong is if the value is greater than 127 and your compiler uses signed chars as default.  You can explicitly cast: `int charval = (int)(unsigned char)somechar;`.  In C, a character is just a number, so it is already in its ASCII decimal form.  A `char` represents a single byte of storage.

Comment: @turb The clue is in your spec, 'output its ascii decimal equivalent', output is not conversion, you don't have to convert anything. There's also way to many variables in your code. Just because something is mentioned in a problem spec, doesn't mean you have to create a variable for it.

Answer (score 5):

One crucial lesson (which they never seem to teach in school) is to start with a very simple program, get it working perfectly, then build up, testing at every step.

Your code doesn't compile. Let's strip your code down and start from scratch:

```
void main()
{
}
```

This doesn't compile. Fix it:

```
int main()
{
  return(0);
}
```

Now add some output:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Assignment 2" << endl;
  return(0);
}
```

So far, so good. Now input:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Assignment 2" << endl;

  char somechar;
  cout << "Enter a letter" << endl;
  cin >> somechar >> endl;
  return(0);
}
```

This doesn't compile. Fix it.

And so on. See how it works?

Comment: Completely agree, best answer I've seen on SO for a while. They might teach the language, they rarely teach the craft, most people learn the hard way or give up.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    char a ='a';
    cout << a << " => integer: " << (int)(a) << endl;

    int i = 98;
    cout << i << " => character: " << (char)(i) << endl;

    char b='b';
    cout << b <<" => lower: " << (char)(b+('a'-'A')) << endl;

    char c='c';
    cout << c << " => upper: " << (char)(c-('a'-'A')) << endl;

    int hours = 15;
    cout << hours << " hours => minutes: " << hours * 60 << endl;

    int minutes = 75;
    cout << minutes << " minutes => hours:minutes: " << minutes/60 << ":" << minutes % 60 << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For this you can take a look at `casting`. To cast a character (`char`) to an integer ASCII value, you have to cast an `int` on that `char` value. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        char myvalue;
        cout<<"Enter a character: ";
        cin>>myvalue;
        cout<<endl<<"The ASCII value is: "<<(int)myvalue<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Now because this is homework, I wont finish the steps for you, but it should be pretty straight forward from here.

For more information about `casting`, I highly suggest: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Comment: Beware of signed-default on char.

Comment: thank you, i just needed to see it written ow to do the conversion, we havent really covered any functions yet

Comment: @turb your welcome, just go ahead and accept the answer then :)